# How to count votes, and deal with undefined method 'push' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby, class, push, nomethoderror

My goal is to make a voting machine that counts candidates' votes into totals. Eventually I want to add the option to write-in a candidate, but I'm stuck with this error:

```
undefined method 'push' for nil:NilClass) at line 30.
```

I defined `castVote`, why isn't it being recognized?

```
class Candidate
  attr_accessor :name
  attr_accessor :count, :total

  def initialize(cname)
    @name = cname
    @vote = Array.new
  end

  def totalVotes
    sum = 0
    if @count > 0
      @count.each { |c| sum += c }
      @total = sum
    else
      @total = 0
    end
  end


    def castVote(vote)
      if vote.is_a?(Integer) || vote.is_a?(Float)
      @count.push(vote)
      totalVotes
    end
  end

    #Candidate
    candidate1 = Candidate.new("Donald Duck")
    #Next line is where error occurs
    candidate1.castVote(1)
    candidate1.castVote(1)

    candidate2 = Candidate.new("Minnie Mouse")
    candidate2.castVote(1)

    candidate3 = Candidate.new("Goofy")

    finalResults = Array.new
    finalResults[0] = candidate1
    finalResults[1] = candidate2
    finalResults[2] = candidate3

    finalResults.each { |candidate| puts "Name: " + candidate.name + "Score " + candidate.totalVotes }
end
```

Comment: Note: Ruby generally encourages people to write method names like `cast_vote` where it's all lower-case.

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". I'd recommend reading "[How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)” as it'll help you for future questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You left out the `@count` instance variable in your `initialize` method so it's nil everywhere in that class and never gets initialized:

```
class Candidate
  attr_accessor :name
  attr_accessor :count, :total

  def initialize(cname)
    @name = cname
    @vote = Array.new
    @count = []
  end

  def totalVotes
    sum = 0
    if @count.length > 0
      @count.each { |c| sum += c }
      @total = sum
    else
      @total = 0
    end
  end


    def castVote(vote)
      if vote.is_a?(Integer) || vote.is_a?(Float)
      @count.push(vote)
      totalVotes
    end
  end

    #Candidate
    candidate1 = Candidate.new("Donald Duck")
    #Next line is where error occurs
    candidate1.castVote(1)
    candidate1.castVote(1)

    candidate2 = Candidate.new("Minnie Mouse")
    candidate2.castVote(1)

    candidate3 = Candidate.new("Goofy")

    finalResults = Array.new
    finalResults[0] = candidate1
    finalResults[1] = candidate2
    finalResults[2] = candidate3

    finalResults.each { |candidate| puts "Name: " + candidate.name + "Score " + candidate.totalVotes }
end
```

Comment: While I agree with the reason I don't agree with the solution. `@count` should be an array, and the `totalVotes` method should test `@count.length` instead of just `@count`

Comment: sorry fixed that, it was an oversight, thanks for pointing that out